# I cant install facebook.client package on my visual studio 2013 because am running windows 8.1

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add a Facebook log in feature to a windows phone 8 app that i am building, i managed to install the Facebook Software development kit but for the Facebook.client package am having incompatibility issues.

Sources on the net tell me that its because the Facebook.Client 0.9.0-alpha is designed to run on windows 8 machine only.

Does anybody have a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of Windows 8.1, I think you are using Visual Studio V4.5.1. And this package is available for V4.5 and below. So the problem is ocured. You can try it in a project which one is building in Visual Studio V4.5

Comment: how can we change the version of windows phone app

Comment: Go to the project properties in solution, In Application tab there is Targate Framework: Select from the dropdown.